# GPU with OpenCL is slower than CPU. Why?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

Environment:

- Intel i7-9750H
- Intel UHD Graphics 630
- Nvidia GTX1050 (Laptop)
- Visual studio 2019 / C++
- OpenCV 4.4
- OpenCL 3.0 (intel) / 1.2 (nvidia)

I'm trying to use OpenCL to speed up my code. But the result shows CPU is faster than GPU.
How could I speed up my code?

```
void GetHoughLines(cv::Mat dst) {
    cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);

    int img_w = dst.size().width; // 5000
    int img_h = dst.size().height; // 4000

    cv::UMat tmp_dst = dst.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);
    cv::UMat tmp_mat = cv::UMat(dst.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        tmp_mat = tmp_mat.mul(tmp_dst);
    }
}
```

It took about 3000ms when I used only CPU.
When I used Intel UHD Graphics 630, it took 3500ms.
And I also tried GTX1050, but it took about 3000ms.

Please give me some ideas to speed it up. I should make it at least 1000ms.
Should I use AMP or OpenMP? But as I know, they can only compute simple operations, not suitable for OpenCV functions.

Comment: Calling that a graphics card is really generous, that's why. Intel's embedded GPU is notoriously slow, as in it's the bare minimum you can put on a chip to get actual graphics on the screen, not much more. You'll get much better results on a discrete GPU. A mid-range AMD or NVidia card will likely perform significantly better.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your reply. As you comment, I tried to use Nvidia GPU. But it is still slow. Do you have other idea to speed up?

Comment: Get a faster GPU. Consider using a GPU-on-demand service, like a cloud-hosted option, if you just need to do a few quick runs. Look at any algorithmic improvements you can make. Use a profiler to find out if there's any optimizations you can make. See if you really need 1000 iterations. Etc.

Comment: A 1050 isn't the fastest GPU either. You'll need at least a 1070 or 1080 to see any real gains, and those are pretty much obsolete since the 3000 series is out now. Try CUDA directly if that's an option for a quick test.

Comment: I don't know exactly how open cv implemented open CL but i imagine your matrix has to be copied to and from the gpu for each loop iteration which will be inefficient, manually written open CL is likely to be faster

Comment: I agree with @AlanBirtles - unless OpenCV specifically optimises away buffer operations and pipelines OpenCL kernel submission to the command queue, simply applying 1000 matrix multiplications in sequence could be thrashing the buffers. I'm unfortunately not familiar with OpenCV, so I can't make any specific recommendations in that regard.

Comment: Thank you for advice @tadman, AlanBirtles, pmdj
I will find other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, Your code is slow because the way OpenCV uses OpenCL is inefficient.
It has nothing to do with the underlying hardware.

In order for OpenCL code (or any GPU related code for that matter) to be efficient, it is crucial for the host side code to properly utilize the GPU. To name a few principles:

- Saturate the GPU by **asynchronously** enqueuing many computations (kernels).
- Avoid unnecessary synchronizations.
- Avoid unnecessary memory copies between host CPU and GPU device.

Even if you write the most optimized GPU kernels, but fail to adhere to these basics, you are very unlikely to gain any performance boosts.

The OpenCV codebase is a great example of how **not** to adhere to these principles.

As for your example, if you rewrite your code to avoid memory copies and use device memory explicitly, you might witness a reasonable performance:

```
auto frame1 = cv::UMat(size, format, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);
auto frame2 = cv::UMat(size, format, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);
auto frame3 = cv::UMat(size, format, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);

for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cv::multiply(frame1, frame2, frame3);
}
```

But in any case, I recommend you learn using the OpenCL API without OpenCV.

Comment: That's exactly what I've found. OpenCV's architecture is not conducive to modern asynchronous work, so no wonder they internally can't really win much.

Comment: Thank you so much. I should learn more about programming.

Answer (score -1):

I see the problem there even tho I have never used this lib and I prefer to use my OpenCl code instead. You see your cv::ocl lib. may execute your mutiplication code in parallel and very efficiently. But even if that is the case you have problems on transfering the buffers to make this execution. Whene you use
tmp_mat = tmp_mat.mul(tmp_dst);
OpenCl and C++ may asume that you want to use your tmp_table at any moment so after every calc. in for loop it transfers the data from cpu to gpu and back this may lag the proccess significantly. You must use a method know in graphics comunity as instancing of a process. So it makes the same calculation again and again in the gpu and it transfers the buffers in start and finish of the proccess this way you can achive in average 30 times faster code in GPU than in CPU. I know that because I have too Intel CPU. Be aware in order to run OpenCl code in Invidia you must have modules that make your code compatible for INVIDIA in other words cuda code. If you dont have done this your GPU code may run on Intels GPU that it is slower than the bigger INVIDIA GPU!

Comment: You can see if you want my progress on GPU code via my git. https://github.com/DimitrisGkofas/Python.git There you will find ways to run OpenCl and make your own kernels (programs) for gpu it is a siplyfied API for starters like you.