# Why do OpenCV calls to UMat operations sometimes take half of a second to complete?

Tags: c++, opencv, time, opencl

My first foray into using a GPU has been disappointing due to weird timing results. Below is a snippet of code using UMat in OpenCV to find dead-space at the top and bottom of a binary image.  Most of the time the findNonZero call excutes in less than one msec, but occasionally it takes more than 500 msec!  The delay seems independent of the size of the result.  Can someone offer an explanation and fix?

```
    UMat bin; 
    // bin is loaded with a binary image of about 60 x 60;

    int top = bin.rows;
    int bottom = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bin.cols; i++)
    {
        UMat r = bin.col(i);
        vector<Point> pxls;
        findNonZero( r, pxls);
        cout << pxls << endl;
        if (!pxls.empty())
        {
            if (pxls.front().y < top) top = pxls.front().y;
            if (pxls.back().y > bottom) bottom = pxls.back().y;
        }
    }
```

Here is the report on my OpenCL support:

```
1 GPU devices are detected.
name:              AMD KAVERI (DRM 2.50.0, 5.8.0-36-generic, LLVM 11.0.0)
available:         1
imageSupport:      0
OpenCL_C_Version:  OpenCL C 1.1 

Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 20.2.6
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     AMD KAVERI (DRM 2.50.0, 5.8.0-36-generic, LLVM 11.0.0)
  Device Vendor                                   AMD
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 20.2.6
  Driver Version                                  20.2.6
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.1 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Max compute units                               8
  Max clock frequency                             720MHz
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
  Preferred work group size multiple              64
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2142642176 (1.995GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           1499849523 (1.397GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       32768 bits (4096 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   No
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     16
  Max constant buffer size                        1499849472 (1.397GiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      0ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64
```

Comment: I've also found that the results from OpenCL for warpPolar(...) are similarly slow and actually return corrupted data.  I'd add some figures to illustrate, but I don't see an option to upload images here.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL code is efficient only if you use the API in an efficient way. OpenCV codebase uses OpenCL very inefficiently and also facilitates inefficient usage patterns via its 'transparent API' (cv::UMat).

Some examples of inefficiencies:

- Lazy compilation of kernel code (can take lots of milliseconds on the first time you invoke an opencv function)
- Unnecessary allocations and memory transfers.
- Unnecessary CPU-GPU synchronizations.

Some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907132/gpu-with-opencl-is-slower-than-cpu-why/64932685#64932685).

It is hard to know exactly what makes your code inefficient as you do not share the way you initialize your cv::UMat. But here are some general tips.

1. Explicitly make sure you allocate GPU memory

`auto mat = cv::UMat(size, format, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);`

2. Call the OpenCV API function once outside your main loop to make sure it is compiling necessary OpenCL kernels.
3. Do the actual work, but use as little OpenCV API calls as possible.
   So for example, performing  `findNonZero( r, pxls)` separately on each column is a bad idea.
   Even if there is an OpenCL backend for `findNonZero` (you need to check the implementation to make sure), OpenCV will probably synchronize the GPU on each call. Very bad in terms of performance.
   Better to call it on the whole buffer at once and later process the results by column.
4. Understand that this is all hopeless, learn to use OpenCL and proper GPU profiling tools to really understand what is going on. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your observations!  This was an exercise to understand what affects the timing, so the column-by-column example wasn't meant to be efficient.  With 90% of the findNonZero calls (just that call, not the whole program) returning in about 0.13 msec, and the remainder returning in about 504 msec, it's something odd I'd like to understand.  If it were consistently slow, I'd just give up on the function, but the inconsistency makes we wonder if there is some tweak that would improve it.  And yes, I do see an OpenCL-specific backend for findNonZero in the opencv source.

Comment: To fully understand what is going on you must profile the code using a tool that can detect OpenCL API calls and kernel execution. Such as CodeXL in your case.